# mono c#. DataRow: "Field" extension method missing?

Tags: c#, mono, datarow

I've often used the DataRow object (or DataRowCollection) when programming C# in Windows (.NET Framework 3 and 3.5). 
Now, I want to use it in a C# program developed with mono in Linux. 
My problem is: I don't find the "Field" extension method of DataRow when using mono... anyone can help me, please ?

Thanks in advance.

(example: `return ds.Table[0].Rows[0].Field<int>(0)` )

Answer (score 5):

By looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), Field is defined in System.Data.DataSetExtensions. I'm not sure if it's available in Mono, but try adding a "using" statement for this namespace. If the namespace is not found, maybe you need to add a reference in your project.

Answer (score 0):

The extension methods you're referring to are defined in **System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll**. If that assembly is part of the Mono distribution, you should add a reference to it. If it's not, you could try copying it from an MS .NET installation and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

How is that different from `GetInt32(0)`?

Comment: Because if your column contains nulls, the Field method lets you do `row.Field<int?>(0)` and get back a nullable int with no value when the underlying value in the DataRow is actually `DBNull.Value`. It's a lot nicer than checking for DBNull every time or handling an exception.

Comment: Also, DataRow doesn't have a GetInt32 method. I think you might be thinking of a DataReader.

Comment: Arg, I was sure I remember that DataRow implemented IDataRecord, but on closure inspection the docs say otherwise :(  That would have made too much sense, I suppose.